# Laravel beanstalkd queue repeating jobs before retry time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, beanstalkd

I've configured a queuing on Laravel 5.4 using the "beanstalkd" queue driver ... I deployed it on CentOS 7 (cPanel) and installed [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html)... but I've two main problems

1. In the logs, I found this exception "local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '{dbname}.failed_jobs' doesn't exist" So **Question #1** is .. Should I configure any database tables for "beanstalkd" queue driver, If so could you please state these tables structure?
2. Also I've configured the queue:work command in the Supervisor config file as following

> ```
> [program:test-queue]
> process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
> command=php /home/****/****/artisan queue:work beanstalkd --sleep=3 --tries=3
> autostart=true
> autorestart=true
> user=gcarpet
> numprocs=8
> redirect_stderr=true
> stdout_logfile= /home/*****/*****/storage/logs/supervisor.log
> ```

3. I found that the supervisor.log contained multiple calls for the job even after the first call was "Processed" .. **Question #2** I dispatched the job once but the job was pushed in to the queue several times, I need a solution for this problem I don't want the same job to pushed multiple times in the queue?

   > ```
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:15] Processing: App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:15] Processing: App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:15] Failed:     App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:24] Processed:  App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:24] Processing: App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:33] Processed:  App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:33] Processing: App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:41] Processed:  App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:41] Processing: App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > [2019-05-14 09:08:41] Failed:     App\Jobs\{JobName}
   > ```

   4. Please note the time difference between processed and failed jobs, Also I had set the driver 'retry_after' to 900 once and to 90 another time .. And I didn't feel it made any difference.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the table using the migration as [documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs).

```
php artisan queue:failed-table
php artisan migrate
```

3. The job failed, so it is [retried](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dispatching-jobs).

This behaviour is specified by the 'tries' option that either your queue worker receives on the command line

`php artisan queue:work --tries=3`

...or the `tries` property of the specific job.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

class Reader implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $tries = 5;
}
```

You currently are seeing that jobs retry 3 times, then fail. 
Check your logging output and the `failed_jobs` table to see what exceptions have been thrown and fix those appropriately.

A job is retried whenever the `handle` method throws. 
After a couple of retried, the job will `fail` and the `failed()` method will be invoked. 
Failed jobs will be stored in the `failed_jobs` table for later reference or [manual retrying](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#retrying-failed-jobs).

4. Also note: there is a *timeout* and a *retry after* which need to be set independently.

> The --timeout value should always be at least several seconds shorter than your  retry_after configuration value. This will ensure that a worker processing a given job is always killed before the job is retried. If your --timeout option is longer than your retry_after configuration value, your jobs may be processed twice.

See, [Job Expirations & Timeouts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but still same problem at question #2 the job process multiple times ... I followed your references and set these attributes in the job class "public $tries = 1; public $retryAfter = 180;public $timeout = 120;.. and the job failed and in the failed job table I found this exception exception 'Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException' with message 'A queued job has been attempted too many times. The job may have previously timed out.' .. could you please update you answer with proper setting for retries and time out, so I can accept the answer.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you restart your supervisor processes after making the changes in the Laravel app?  Once the queue:work command is executed the app is not rebooted until the queue has been restarted.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild If I'm restarting the queue using this command Artisan::call("queue:restart") in side the Laravel app ... is it working as I'm restarting the queue from the supervisor

Comment: In the end if you use supervisor: yes. queue:restart does not actually 'restart' the queue but rather kills it after finishing the current job. It's up to supervisor to restart the queue.